# Date arithmetic in Java, adding 3 months from today

Tags: java, date, calendar

My program is about generating (producing) a Kurosawa and making the customers produce it.

Every time we generate a Kurosawa, we have to print its id, its production date and expiration date, which is 3 months from the production date.

My problem is: *How can I calculate the date after 3 months?*

Comment: BTW, What is a Kurosawa?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it's a sake brewed in Saku, Nagano, Japan.

Answer (score 15):

Use the built-in [Java Calendar API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
```

Refer to the API for exactly how to print out the date, in the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use the much more powerful and easier to use [Joda Time Library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateMidnight productionDate = new DateMidnight();
DateMidnight expirationDate = productionDate.plusMonths(3);
System.out.println(expirationDate.toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

Joda Time has many advantages over the built-in [Java Calendar API.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Why use Joda for something as simple as adding 3 months to a date?

Comment: You are right but when you add 3 months to a java.util.Date/Calendar you manipulate the same instance which could be error-prone. The Joda-Time objects are immutable. And I think you normally do something more than with date's than just add 3 months. 
I hope that Java7 will include Joda-Time(JSR310)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()            // Determine today’s date.
         .plusMonths( 3 )  // Add three months.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Add three months, letting java.time do the math.

```
LocalDate threeMonthsLater = today.plusMonths( 3 ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the [Java Calendar Library](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with date arithmetic JODA works better, as Calendar likes timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

/*The java class Calendar is abstract.  So you need to use the GregorianCalendar class.*/

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar gC = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();

java.util.Date yourDate = new java.util.Date();
gC.setTime(yourDate);
```

/*Add 3 months*/

```
gC.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 3);
```

/*to go back 1 week*/

```
gC.add(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
```

Comment: The [getInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29) methods of Calendar are static so you can use them.

Comment: And are preferred, because getInstance() is a static factory method (see Effective Java, Joshua Bloch) which will try to determine the best time for your locale.